# Can I generate new excel files from one template based on one column /constant/ with variable data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, cpu-word, auto-generate

I have this [excel] file:

[IMAGE-xlsfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISIln.png)

I The customers every day are different (because they may paid some of documents)...and the rows with data for every of them.

Can I create from this .xls file for every customer new excel (or word) file with the rows with doc.#, paid..?
I need some help because I have to create [letters] every day for the clients (they are more than 500) or some other idea how to make the task more fast?

Thank You : )

P.S. I'm not programmer
[excel-vba][word] [excel-formula]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fixed format. I strongly recommend using "Power query" (
if you want it to look more professional use "PowerBI"). You can link the customer files to your main file. You can update your tables with one click.

Useful links:

for unchangeable customer filter
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MlDYKPxznQ

for changeable customer filter
https://exceleratorbi.com.au/pass-excel-parameter-power-query/

Don't panic, you don't have to know software to use it.